# Joining two IQueryables

Tags: entity-framework, ienumerable, iqueryable, outer-join

My issue is a bit hard to explain, so bear with me, I'm going to try and explain the best I can and provide the most information I can.

So I have two tables:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item : BaseModel
{
  [Key]
  [Column("Id")]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [Column("DescriptionId")]
  public Guid DescriptionId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Id")]
  public LanguageText LanguageText { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("DescriptionId")]
  public LanguageText DescriptionText { get; set; }
}



[Table("Shops")]
 [Serializable]
 public class Shop: BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("ItemId")]
    public Guid? ItemId{ get; set; }

    [Column("Closed")]
    public DateTime? Closed{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public Item ItemModel{ get; set; }
}
```

My queries

```
var items= itemRepository.GetAll()
                        .Include(x => x.LanguageText)
                        .Include(x => x.DescriptionText);




var querableShops = shopRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(x =>!x.Closed.HasValue || (x.Closed.HasValue && x.Closed.Value >= Expiration))
                        .GroupJoin(items, s => s.ItemId, i => i.Id, (x, y) => x);
```

The interesting thing happens when I do my queries. When I debug querableShops and want to check out my ItemModel it is null unless I expand the Result View for items first. Because of this my items are not shown in the data grid, unless i check the items manually in debug beforehand. I think the problem is that my items are IQueryable, I did try converting it to IEnumerable, but that didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: What happens in `GetAll`? And do the repositories share the same context?

Comment: GetAll() returns the DBSet. Yes the repositories are in the same context

Comment: I think lazy loading is enabled in your project , so you need to load them eagerly, so converting them to ToList() will help.
db.itemRepository.Include(x => x.LanguageText)
                 .Include(x => x.DescriptionText)
                 .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try to call ToList() to enumerate the result.

Comment: As I said in my last sentence, I did try that.

Comment: I cannot see anything enumerates the items in your query,  so if you try to use ToList with the items query,  you should get something when you use toList with the final query.

Comment: if I do that I get the following error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Namespace.Item'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Is that when you call to list for this query? var items= itemRepository.GetAll()
                        .Include(x => x.LanguageText)
                        .Include(x => x.DescriptionText);

Comment: yes, like so: var items= itemRepository.GetAll() .Include(x => x.LanguageText) .Include(x => x.DescriptionText).ToList();

Comment: But I've also tried this: var querableShops = shopRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(x =>!x.Closed.HasValue || (x.Closed.HasValue && x.Closed.Value >= Expiration))
                        .GroupJoin(items.ToList(), s => s.ItemId, i => i.Id, (x, y) => x);

Answer (score 0):

This is because by `(x, y) => x` you only select Shops and no items from the query. EF always tries to determine if entities that are part of the query really make a difference for the end result. If not, they are ignored. In this case, the `items` don't make a difference because -

1. They are not projected to the result set
2. The join is an outer join, so they don't have any selective effect.

Effectively, you only query `Shops` and I think the generated SQL will just show a simple query on this table only.

Note that a `GroupJoin` is not the same as an `Include`. If you want Shops *and* their items you must fetch the shops with an `Include` statement. The trouble of this repository layer is that this will probably incur responsibility conflicts (architecturally, that is, not technically).